# Store variables correctly in an ArrayList during a loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, store

I have some problems storing variables in an arrayList. The propose of the programm is to read from one file (A) , read another text file (B) and than compare how much percentage covers the occured vocabulary from A in B. For this reason, I store every word which occurs togheter in **neuS**. And here comes the problem. If I try to get the output, it seems to store the values random times inside! So for example I get output like:

```
elektrotechnik und
die bedeutendste
die bedeutendste
und simulation
erleben die
eine form
eine form
```

So there are some words (correctly said Ngramms, because I store always two words togheter), which are only one time inside **neuS** but others only one time. I also have seen the output like three times the same. I want all words only stored **once** inside neuS.  What am I'm doing wrong? The code isn't complete, there are some code which I supposse that's irrelevant for this issue.

Thanks!

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("informatik_test.txt"));
String str;

// 
while ((sCurrentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    arr = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
        String s = (arr[i].toString() + " " + arr[i + 1].toString())
                .toLowerCase();
        if (null == (hash.get(s))) {
            hash.put(s, 1);
        } else {
            int x = hash.get(s) + 1;
            hash.put(s, x);
        }
    }
    //

    ArrayList< String> words = new ArrayList< String>();
    ArrayList< String> neuS = new ArrayList< String>();
    ArrayList< Long> neuZ = new ArrayList< Long>();

    // Read all Lines from a file
    for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
        String h[] = line.split("   ");

        words.add(h[0].toLowerCase());

    }
    //
    for (String x : hash.keySet()) {
        summe = summe + hash.get(x);
        long neu = hash.get(x);
        for (String s : words) {

            if (x.equals(s)) {
                neuS.add(x);
                neuZ.add(neu);
                disc = disc + 1;
            }

        }
    }
    // Testing which word for output -->! THE PROBLEM!!
    for (String m : neuS) {
        System.out.println(m);
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of Object is 'hash'? (hash.put(s, 1);)

Comment: It must be a HashMap, look at the methods being used.

Comment: Yes, it's an HashMap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the words in neuS to only be stored once, than neuS should be a HashSet. As it is, because both `words` and `neuS` are arrays, if words contains duplicates, neuS will contain duplicates too.

Side note: for `String h[] = line.split("   ");` you have 2 spaces in the split. Is that deliberate?

Comment: YES :) If I use it, it works. But how does HashSet work? Will the lines equally been added into **neuZ** because there I need to store all of them, beacause later I make a sum of theses values.

So **neuS** as HashSet and **neuZ** as ArrayList will get right percentage?

And yes, the split is of the structure from my data ;)

Comment: All Sets in Java ensure that objects only occur once within them. HashSet does this through hashing, which is normally more efficient than the common alternative way to create a set: through a Tree. I'd recommend reading about data structures like Sets and lists, as well as hashing.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn neuS into a HashSet. It would fix your output.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String s : words) { 
    if (x.equals(s)) {
        neuS.add(x);
        neuZ.add(neu);
        disc = disc + 1;
    }
}
```

You should add `break;` after `disc = disc + 1;` and you should check if x is in neuS before adding it.